# Bottom bar in CoordinatorLayout. How to?

Tags: android, android-layout

Could someone please provide an example of how to create a bar with buttons at the bottom within CoordinatorLayout?  My app consists of AppBar (top) that contains buttons invoking application-wide action.  However, I'd like to have a view specific buttons placed at the bottom.
I'm not sure if this UI design is still supported/recommended when using the new Disign Library and AppCompat.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.